# How to customize the tinymce menu

Tags: jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4, rich-text-editor, tinymce-plugins

I want to customization the format option from the menu bar.  We were able to customize the options, However, facing the below problem.

[image]

We want what user seeing on hovering the Formats should appear in the place of format.

The list should be as follow.

1. Format (menubar)
   Headings
   Inline
   Blocks
   Clear Formatting

We want to eliminate the Formats option from the drop-down.

Below is our code.

```
 menu: { 
    edit: {title: 'Edit', items: 'undo redo | cut copy paste pastetext | selectall'},
    insert: {title: 'Insert', items: 'link media | template hr'},
    view: {title: 'View', items: 'showblock visualaid'},
    format: {title: 'Format', items: 'formats removeformat'},
    table: {title: 'Table', items: 'inserttable tableprops deletetable | cell row column'},
    tools: {title: 'Tools', items: 'spellchecker code'}
  },
  style_formats: [
   { title: 'Headings', items: [
      { title: 'Heading 3', block: 'h3' },
      { title: 'Heading 4', block: 'h4' },
      { title: 'Heading 5', block: 'h5' },
      { title: 'Heading 6', block: 'h6' }
    ] },
    {title: 'Inline', items: [
              {title: 'Bold', icon: 'bold', format: 'bold'},
              {title: 'Italic', icon: 'italic', format: 'italic'},
              {title: 'Underline', icon: 'underline', format: 'underline'},
              {title: 'Strikethrough', icon: 'strikethrough', format: 'strikethrough'},
              {title: 'Superscript', icon: 'superscript', format: 'superscript'},
              {title: 'Subscript', icon: 'subscript', format: 'subscript'}
          ]},
          {title: 'Blocks', items: [
              {title: 'Paragraph', format: 'p'},
              {title: 'Blockquote', format: 'blockquote'},
              {title: 'Div', format: 'div'},
              {title: 'Pre', format: 'pre'},
     {title : 'Code', block : 'pre', classes : 'ckeditor_codeblock', exact: true}
          ]}
      ]
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: if i understand correctly you need to use these 2 options [`Using custom formats`](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-formatting/#usingcustomformats) and [`Removing a format`](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-formatting/#removingaformat) in order to create your own custom formats

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam - In screenshot, you will see there is option like

Format(menubar) -> format -> etc etc etc. I want to remove second format option and have directly headings,inline,blocks option under format (menubar)